# Async calls workaround

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have a JS script to perform service call, which might load some data and then put it into localStorage. Unfortunately, because of some async issues, my localStorage is empty when I try to access it. 
JS is not my primary language and I don't have deep understanding on how async calls work, so I want to learn from my current example.

JS code to perform request:

```
    function getRM() {
      var handleResponse = function (status, response) {
          localStorage.setItem('return_matrix', response);
      }
      var http=new XMLHttpRequest();
      var handleStateChange = function () {
           switch (http.readyState) {
              case 0 : case 1 : case 2 : case 3 : break;
              case 4 : // COMPLETED
                  handleResponse(http.status, http.responseText);
                  break;
              default: alert("error");
           }
      }
      http.onreadystatechange=handleStateChange;
      http.open("GET",'{% url 'returnMatrix'  %}', true);
      http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
      http.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', '{{  csrf_token }}');
      http.send(null);
    }
```

JS code to handle local storage item applied to window.onload:

```
    function createTableData() {
      if (localStorage.getItem('return_matrix') === null) {
          getRM()
      }
      var returnMatrix = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('return_matrix'));
      //...
      /*save data to locat storage*/
      returnMatrix['years'] = years; // here I get an error that returnMatrix is null
      returnMatrix["present_value"] = sum;
      returnMatrix["actual_contributions"] = actualContributions;
      localStorage.setItem('return_matrix', JSON.stringify(returnMatrix))
      //...
    }
```

Comment: async/await or promise might be what you need

Comment: Why don't you use `promises` or `async/await`

Comment: Thank you guys, I am so new to this so didn't know about that.

Comment: Read [Async JS: The Complete Guide](https://medium.com/@rcepeda1993/async-js-the-complete-guide-670b4cf906c6) if you want absolute clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to resume code after an async thing is with a callback function. That would look something like this:

```
function getRM(callback) { // <--- accepts a callback param
  const handleResponse = function (status, response) {
    localStorage.setItem('return_matrix', response);
    callback(); // <--- calling the callback
  })

  const http=new XMLHttpRequest();
  // ...etc
}
```

And it would get used something like this:

```
function createTableData() {
  if (localStorage.getItem('return_matrix') === null) {
    getRM(doWork);
  } else {
    doWork();
  }
}

// I split this out into a helper function because it sometimes needs to be
//   called synchronously, sometimes asynchronously, and i didn't want to
//   duplicate the code. 
function doWork() {
  const returnMatrix = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('return_matrix');
  //... etc
}
```

---

Callbacks work, but can be somewhat combersome when you want to chain them together or deal with errors. Another common technique which improves on this is Promises. A promise is an object that represents an eventual value. You can get access to that eventual value by calling the promise's .then method, and providing a callback.

Many libraries for doing http requests (eg, [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios), [fetch](https://github.com/whatwg/fetch)) will return a promise, and so you can work with them without doing anything extra. In your example though you manually did an XHR, and this doesn't have promises built in.  But you can still add them if you want, something like this:

```
function getRM() {
  // creating a promise object
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const handleResponse = function (status, response) {
      localStorage.setItem('return_matrix', response);
      resolve(); //<--- calling resolve instead of callback
    }

    const http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // ...etc
  });
}
```

And you'll use it like this:

```
function createTableData() {
  if (localStorage.getItem('return_matrix') === null) {
    getRM().then(doWork);
  } else {
    doWork();
  }
}
```

---

Now that the code is using promises, one further refinement we can do is to use async/await, which is a syntax for working with promises a little easier. That version would look like this:

```
async function createTableData() {
  if (localStorage.getItem('return_matrix') === null) {
    await getRM();
  }

  // I've moved the code back in line, since it's no longer needed in 2 places
  const http=new XMLHttpRequest();
  //... etc
}
```

And now it's back to looking pretty much like what you originally had, except getRM now returns a promise, and createTableData will await the resolution of that promise.

Comment: thank you very much for your explanation. I thin I understood the syntax of promises and async/await. I've also decided to read about that more, but I think your answer resolves my issue completely. Thank you very much.